# Loading CSS before dynamically appending html to body

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

The way my page works at the moment:

1) Javascript looks at my URL, i.e. www.domain1.com/query <-- and saves this query after the slash as a variable. The query is generated random letters and numbers (e.g. KL_Kg62hp).

2) Fetch method is used with the latter query @ www.domain2.com/query and all JSON data received is stored as var obj.

3) Necessary CSS stylesheets and an HTML string with template literals is appended to body -- > $("body").html(template).

4) To my understanding, the browser goes through the code twice - first it appends the HTML string to body with JS and only then it reads the CSS appended files.

1) Tried appending necessary CSS stylesheets to the head element after data fetch.

2) Tried hardcoding all possible CSS stylesheets in the head element and deleting all those that don't match my query after data is fetched.

3) Tried to two data fetch functions - one for receiving necessary stylesheet and the following one for retrieving all the rest of the data.

4) Tried body onload = 'dataRouter()'.

5) Tried appending CSS link to head separately and before appending HTML template to body.

```
<html>
<script>

function dataRouter() {
  var query = window.location.pathname.split("/")[1];

  fetch("www.domain2.com/" + query)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => (obj = data))
    .then(function() {
        dataobj = obj;
        let template1CssLink = `<link href="./Styles/${obj.typeOfCss}.css" rel="stylesheet"/>`
        let template1 = `<div> Data for the first page: ${obj} </div>`
        let template2CssLink = `<link href="./Styles/${obj.typeOfCss}.css" rel="stylesheet" />`
        let template2 = `<div> Data received the second page: ${obj} </div>`
        let template3CssLink = `<link href="./Styles/${obj.typeOfCss}.css" rel="stylesheet" />`
        let template3 = `<div> Data received for the third page: ${obj} </div>`

        if (obj.typeOfCss === "firstPageCss") {
          $("head").html(template1CssLink)
          $("body").html(template1)
        }

        if (obj.typeOfCss === "secondPageCss") {
          $("head").html(template2CssLink)
          $("body").html(template2)
        }

        if (obj.typeOfCss === "thirdPageCss") {
          $("head").html(template3CssLink)
          $("body").html(template3)
        }
      }
    }

dataRouter()


</script>

<body>

</body>
</html>
```

---

Random response from domain2 looks like this:

```
{
"someParagraph" : "someText",
"someImg" : "somePicture",
"typeOfCss" : "firstPage"
}
```

What I want is for the browser to append necessary CSS first, read through it and only then append HTML.

Comment: CSS is not appended separately, it is parsed together with the markup.

Comment: `.html()` doesn't append, it replaces the element contents completely.

Comment: How can you tell what order things are happening, and why does it matter? The final rendering will be based on the new HTML and the new CSS.

Comment: The text in div loads  and only after ~a second styles are applied.